# Bugzilla Seems to point to Incorrect DB after mysql.sock file is missing

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, bugzilla

I have a XAMPP setup where my Bugzilla was connected to the MYSQL DB.

Everything was working fine until one fine day when this error showed up:

> "Can't connect to the database. Error: Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)   Is your
>   database installed and up and running?   Do you have the correct
>   username and password selected in localconfig?

As described in many similar questions in this forum, I tried the following options:

1. There is another mysql.sock file in

> /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

I modified the my.cnf file to point to this socket file.

2. I modified the Bugzilla `localconfig` file so that Bugzilla points to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

In both the above cases, Bugzilla comes up alive, but does not show any of the previous projects/bugs. The DB name has not been modified anywhere in Bugzilla. It seems to be pointing to some other DB.

What could be the problem here? 
Why does the "mysql.sock" file go missing? How to generate it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: mysql.sock is the mysqld daemon's socket file for "local" connections. you don't create it. the daemon will create it for you.

Comment: Agreed. But why does this file disappear? How do we instruct the daemon to recreate the file?

Comment: if the file doesn't exist, then the daemon isn't running, or the daemon's creating it somewhere else. its location CAN be overridden by command-line args to the daemon.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the my.cnf file to point to an existing socket. But why does the DB turn out to be empty even though nothing has been modified there.

Comment: do you have multiple mysql instances installed? picking a random mysql.sock file doesn't help you much if it's the socket file for some OTHER install/instance of mysql.

Comment: I believe I do.Could you please tell me how I can recreate the mysql.sock file for this instance of mysql? Or should I modify the my.cnf file?

Comment: Like I said. you don't create the socket. you modify your my.ini/my.cnf to specify the location, then start mysql. if you have multiple instances, then you may be starting the wrong copy, and pointing to a data dir that doesn't contain your DBs